# pg_hba.conf entry query

Tags: postgresql, authentication, access-control, pg-hba.conf

I'm trying to formulate a rule from pg_hba.conf file. Thus far I have understood that `pg_hba.conf` file is used to give access to the specific user for a specific host. But I just want to take a second opinion hence this question.

Given that I defined a set of entry in `pg_hba.conf`:

```
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 md5

host    all            all             111.121.10.32/32         md5
```

Then does Postgres guarantee the only way anyone can connect to Postgres is either using `localhost` or from `111.121.10.32` and not other IP will be able to access the Postgres server.

Is my understanding correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your understanding is correct. For every connection attempt, each line in `pg_hba.conf` is checked in turn. The first matching line applies and the connection then either passes with this or fails trying. Much like a firewall. [The manual:](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/auth-pg-hba-conf.html)

> The first record with a matching connection type, client address, requested database, and user name is used to perform authentication. There is no “fall-through” or “backup”: if one record is chosen and the authentication fails, subsequent records are not considered. **If no record matches, access is denied.**

Bold emphasis mine.

Comment: Thank you very much. On other note is it possible for a client to restart a Postgres server by any means possible.

Comment: @Ratatouille: Please start another *question* (with details) for another question. Comments are not the place.